# Custom Member's Channel Entries Defaulting To "Closed" Status

Tags: channel-entries, members

I created a member group and gave that group permission to add/edit a particular Channel. Whenever a new entry is made by a user in that member group, the status is set to "Closed." I looked at the Channel settings and the default status is set to "Open". When I make entries as a Super Admin, the status is set to "Open."

What do I need to do so that the member group's entries are set to Open?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check if that channel is assigned a status group from CP -> Admin -> Channel Administration -> Channels -> Edit Group Assignments.

Here make sure that you have selected a status "Status Groups".

Comment: Also for the assigned status group you can double check that the member group in question has permission to access each of the statuses.

Comment: Alex's comment is worthy of being an answer. This was the solution when I've seen this happen in the past with non-Super Admin member groups.