# Entries no longer have a "Status" option, and disappear when saved

Tags: entries, status

I recently upgraded to Expression 2.7.1. I'm experiencing problems with publishing, or in this case, republishing entries. In the "Options" tab, the "Status" dropdown is now empty.

When I changed something in a particular entry, it loses it's "Open" status and becomes unpublished, and I'm unable to swtich it back to "Open."

My local test site doesn't have this issue, but my live production site does.

Any ideas or places I should look first?

Thanks,
Jason

Comment: Check your host hasn't limited the number of POST variables in their PHP configuration. Often this is the cause if some fields are not getting updated on channels which have a large number of fields / inputs.

Comment: I know it doesn't help your current predicament but 2.7.3 is the most stable version of the 2.7.x's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your permissions within the status group. Each group that is creating/editing content needs to have permission to each status. So, if the open status is only available to Super Admins and your account isn't a Super Admin, then it won't show Open as an option for you.

Comment: OK I think this actually was the root of the problem. I'm not really sure how this happened, but I went into the Admin>Channel Administration>Channels and had to click on each channel's "Edit Group Assignments" link, and under the dropdown for "Status Groups" had to choose "Statuses." Strange, no idea how that works or how it's undone, but the Open and Closed statuses are now available in all of the entries Options tab. Thanks Jeremy!

Comment: @sonictomb Please mark this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest starting by updating to 2.7.2, which I believe came out in the last day or so. I was having issues setting some field preferences in 2.7.1 that the update seems to have fixed.

Comment: Hey Noah, I updated to 2.7.2, still the same issue unfortunately. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to comment as yet, so 'commenting' here.

The accepted answer and especially sonictombs comment on that answer really helped me.  I had just updated a website from EE1 to EE2.7.2.  All was fine, till I changed a word in an entry on the home page - which promptly disappeared.  I saw this comment, dived in and it solved the issue.

I checked my other channels and some had the default status group assigned and some did not, so had to check each individually.  I could see no obvious correlation to other assignments... hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this question is resolved for you, but I thought I'd note my experience with this as help to others in the future.

*NOTE: this **only** happens if you are in a member group that is **NOT** the super admin group.*

**When you don't have the open/closed options for the "status" field there can be a few problems**:

1. The channel has to have a status assigned to it (as Jeremy mentioned):

   - Go to Admin>Channel Administration>Channels, click on each channel's "Edit Group Assignments" link, and under the dropdown for "Status Groups" choose "Statuses" (or whatever you want.)
     [image: status group field]
2. The User must have permissions to that status (as noted in comment here: [Custom Member's Channel Entries Defaulting To "Closed" Status](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/5622/custom-members-channel-entries-defaulting-to-closed-status))

   - CP -> Admin -> Channel Administration -> Statuses -> [Status Group] -> [Status] --make sure the user group in question has permission to view the status.
     [image: Permissions for the status]
3. For some weird reason neither of these worked for me in one case, where the status group wasn't getting saved to the DB, and I had to manually go into the database to set the status group for each channel. NOTE: don't try this if you're not comfortable in the DB.

   - I went into the exp_channels table, located the status_group column. It said NULL even though I had done step #1 as mentioned above.
   - I edited each channel so the status_group field = 1
   - check to make sure you use the right status group id in the status_group column. You can check this in the exp_statuses table, see the group_id column.
     [image: database]