# Ideas why status is set to closed when entry edited via channel:form?

Tags: channel-entries, status

In this post answer was that membergroup has to have access to all statuses merged to channel: [Custom Member's Channel Entries Defaulting To "Closed" Status](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/5622/custom-members-channel-entries-defaulting-to-closed-status)

I have same issue that when editing entry via channel:form, status goes to closed. So only way to avoid this type of situation is to make custom status group and to allow access to all statuses, so entry should stay open/what-ever status but not closed?

What is the logic behind this? I want to deny access to closed and open, but having access to foo and bar, this is mission impossible because entry goes closed every time someone edit the entry when having the channel attached to default status group.

Feeling nuts to create new status groups just because of this, if the case is really that member has to have access to all statues or otherwise entry goes closed.

Is there a work-around for this, so that channel could have the choice to deny access to open and closed without a worry about entry getting closed everytime it is edited?

Answer (score 1):

Are you including status input in your form? If not, try adding

> <input type="hidden" name="status" value="{status}" />

Comment: Bummer, that I havent yet tried. I was thinking and trying with adding parameter to channel:form tag, but this sounds better. Will try, thank you Yuri!